# void Function(int) isn't a valid override of void Function(dynamic)

Tags: dart

```
class Parent<T> {
  void method(T t) {}
}

class Child extends Parent {
  @override
  void method(int i) {} // error: mentioned_below

  void takesDynamic(dynamic d) {
    takesType(d); // no error
  }

  void takesType(int i) {
    takesDynamic(i); // no error
  }
}
```

Error:

> void Function(int) isn't a valid override of void Function(dynamic)

When I can easily pass `int` to `dynamic` and vice-versa in a method parameter, why do I see the error when I override method.

---

PS:

I am not looking for a solution which is to use `extends Parent<int>` and get it working, I want to know the reason why things are treated differently when I am overriding a method vs calling regular methods.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`void Function(int x)` normally isn't a valid override of `void Function(dynamic x)` because the `int` version is not substitutable for the `dynamic` version.

What are the allowed inputs to `void Function(dynamic)` (the type of `Parent<dynamic>.method`)? *Anything*.

What are the allowed inputs to `void Function(int)` (the type of `Child.method`)?  Only `int`s.

Such an override therefore could violate the contract of `Parent<dynamic>`'s interface. (For example, what if you had an instance of `Child` and passed it to something that expected `Parent<dynamic>`, which then invoked `method('not an int')` on it?)

(Note that this is not specific to method overrides.  **In general, a function that takes a narrower type cannot be used where a function that takes a wider type is expected**, even if the narrower type derives from the wider type.)

Dart does allow you to use the [`covariant` keyword](https://dart.dev/guides/language/sound-problems#the-covariant-keyword) to suppress the static type error and explicitly allow the override, but be aware that doing so isn't necessarily type-safe, and you would be responsible for ensuring that you don't get type errors at runtime.

Further reading: [Covariance and contravariance (computer science) from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Covariant_method_parameter_type)