# Error in modifying typedef in Dart, passing String to dynamic and vice-versa

Tags: dart

```
typedef Filter = bool Function(String string);
typedef Filter2 = bool Function(dynamic args);

void main() {
  Filter modified = (dynamic x) => x == 10; // no error, why?
  Filter2 modified2 = (String string) => string.contains('1'); // error, why?
}
```

In first line of `main()` method, when I am modifying `Filter`, I am passing `dynamic` value to `String` which isn't an error. And on the other hand when I passing `String` to `dynamic` in the 2nd line, it's an error.

I don't get that, can anyone explain?

Comment: It's for the same reason why [you can't override such a method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61966135/179715) in a derived class.  A function that takes a `String` argument is *not* substitutable for a function type whose interface allows it to take *any* argument; it would violate the contract of the interface.

Comment: @jamesdlin It was my initial thought too but I didn't know that overriding a `typedef` works the same way as in case of a class, let me close this question. I also request you to vote to close the issue, I casted mine or shall I delete it all together?