# void Function(Subype) isn't a valid override of void Function(ParentType)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a parent type (`IDataProvider`) and a subtype (`ILocalDataProvider`), and then in a class, specify the subtype to take the place of the parent type. Here is what I mean:

```
abstract class IDataProvider {
  ValueType get<ValueType>(String keyToRead);
}

abstract class ILocalDataProvider extends IDataProvider {
  bool isKeyExistent(String key);
}

abstract class IDataSource {
  IDataProvider dataProvider;
}

class LocalDataSource implements IDataSource {
  LocalDataSource({@required this.dataProvider});

  @override
  ILocalDataProvider dataProvider; //*************** ERROR ON THIS LINE **********//
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> 'LocalDataSource.dataProvider=' ('void Function(ILocalDataProvider)')
> isn't a valid override of 'IDataSource.dataProvider=' ('void
> Function(IDataProvider)').

I thought that since ILocalDataProvider is a subtype of IDataProvider, it will be recognised as an IDataProvider?? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/61966135/ and https://dart.dev/guides/language/sound-problems#the-covariant-keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that. The functions' signatures must match exactly. However, you can use a generic parameter like this: `abstract class IDataSource<ProviderType extends IDataProvider> {}`

Comment: Thanks. So the parent would be changed to this: `abstract class IDataSource<ProviderType> {` and the child will be declared like this `class LocalDataSource implements IDataSource<ILocalDataProvider> {`. I have got that working so will accept if that is what you mean.

Comment: almost. The way you did it, now the parameter can take ANY type, which is probably not something you want. To bound the generic parameter to IDataProvider do this: abstract class IDataSource<ProviderType extends IDataProvider >