# Flutter type '(Subtype) => Future<String>' is not a subtype of type '(Supertype) => Future<Object>'

Tags: flutter, dart, generics

I always do the same thing with a FutureBuilder in my flutter app, so I want to get rid of the duplicated code and provide a widget for that.
I have an `abstract interface class Service` and my widget uses the generic types `<T extends Object, S extends Service>`. The class `AuthenticationService` implements my `Service` interface.

My widget looks like this:

```
class NewStandardFutureBuilder<T extends Object, S extends Service>
    extends StatefulWidget {
  const NewStandardFutureBuilder({
    super.key,
    required this.service,
    required this.createFuture,
    required this.builder,
  });

  final S service;
  final Future<T> Function(S) createFuture;
  final DataWidgetBuilder<T> builder;

  @override
  State<NewStandardFutureBuilder> createState() =>
      _NewStandardFutureBuilderState<T, S>();
}

class _NewStandardFutureBuilderState<T extends Object, S extends Service>
    extends State<NewStandardFutureBuilder> {
  late Future<T> future;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    future = widget.createFuture(widget.service) as Future<T>;
  }

  Future<void> load() async {
    setState(() {
      future = widget.createFuture(widget.service as S) as Future<T>;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<T>(
      future: future,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {...},
    );
  }
}
```

I try to use the widget like this:

```
return NewStandardFutureBuilder<String, AuthenticationService>(
  service: AuthenticationService(),
  createFuture: (service) => service.getUsername(),
  builder: (username) => Text('You are logged in as $username'),
);
```

The class AuthenticationService implements the Service interface. I get the error in the `initState`-method:

```
type '(AuthenticationService) => Future<String>' is not a subtype of type '(Service) => Future<Object>'
```

How do I fix this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Ultimately you have to ask yourself if a function that takes an `AuthenticationService` is [*substitutable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) for a function that takes a `Service` argument.  It is not, because code that has a reference to the latter expects to be able to call it with *any* `Service` argument.  Also see: [void Function(int) isn't a valid override of void Function(dynamic)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61966135/).

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly. I am only looking for a way to get rid of redundant code which i have nearly every time I use a future builder because i always check for the connection state. The reason I pass the Service and the Function is because i want to be able to reload (call the load-method) when the user manually reload. I am going to think about a solution where I don't have to pass a Service AND a Function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to make sure your state gets a properly typed widget:

It needs to include `<T, S>`:

```
 extends State<NewStandardFutureBuilder<T,S>> {
```

Then you will get about 3 errors of "unneccessary cast", so just remove those, they are indeed unneccessary.

Answer (score 1):

From, the documentation on [substituting types](https://dart.dev/language/type-system#substituting-types):

> When substituting types, it helps to think in terms of consumers and producers. A consumer absorbs a type and a producer generates a type.
>
> You can replace a consumer’s type with a supertype and a producer’s type with a subtype.

Here, the parameter of the function is a consumer, so you can substitute it with a supertype, but not subtype.

You can see the example on the [methods](https://dart.dev/language/type-system#methods) section. Passing callback function is a similar case to overriding method, as shown in the example.

---

For the solution, you might want to write your code in [algebraic data types](https://dart.dev/language/patterns#algebraic-data-types). It shows an example of having a single method that covers two different types under the same supertype like this:

```dart
sealed class Shape {}

class Square implements Shape {
  final double length;
  Square(this.length);
}

class Circle implements Shape {
  final double radius;
  Circle(this.radius);
}

double calculateArea(Shape shape) => switch (shape) {
      Square(length: var l) => l * l,
      Circle(radius: var r) => math.pi * r * r
    };
```

Comment: The dart-documentation is really helpful, thanks! But it does not really answer my question as it does not offer a specific solution to my problem.