Can you pass subtypes as function parameters in function arguments?
I'm struggling to understand generic types with inherited types.
class EventHubImpl extends EventHub {
  final Map<EventId, Signal1<Event>> _signals = <EventId, Signal1<Event>>{};

  @override
  Connection registerEventHandler<T extends Event>(
    final EventId eventId,
    final void Function(T) handler
  ) {
    if (_signals.containsKey(eventId)) {
      return _signals[eventId]!.connect(handler);
    }

    final Signal1<Event> signal = Signal1<Event>();
    _signals[eventId] = signal;
    return signal.connect(handler);
  }

  @override
  void sendEvent(final Event event) {
    _signals[event.eventId]?.emit(event);
  }
}

I want to make a Map of Signals that take any subtype of Event.
registerEventHandler takes a handler and the handlers parameter must be a sub type of event. On the two calls to connect I get this error:
The argument type 'void Function(T)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'dynamic Function(Event)'.

Why can T not be Event here when I have the template type as <T extends Event>?

In general, you cannot pass a Function(Derived) where a Function(Base) is expected because a Function(Base) could legally be called with any type of Base object, not necessarily with just Derived objects.  Such an assignment would be unsafe, so it generates a type error. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61966636.
You will need to change your handler callback to be of type void Function(Event).  If you can guarantee that it will be invoked only with Events of type T, then you instead could wrap the Function(T) in a Function(Event) that casts its argument to T:
  @override
  Connection registerEventHandler<T extends Event>(
    final EventId eventId,
    final void Function(T) handler
  ) {
    if (_signals.containsKey(eventId)) {
      return _signals[eventId]!.connect((event) => handler(event as T));
    }

